# Trying to use Streaming Standard Scaling

Tags: julia

I am trying to use OnlineStats.jl to perform a streaming standard scaling, but this doesn't seem to be properly scaling values to their ZScore.  Can you spot anything wrong with this math?

```
using OnlineStats
onlineStats = OnlineStats.Series(Mean(), Variance(), Extrema())
fit!(onlineStats, value)
(mean, variance, extrema) = OnlineStats.value(onlineStats)
stdDev = variance^0.5
normed = (value - mean) / stdDev
```

Comment: This code does not work as `T` is not defined. Are you trying to use the first observation only to calculate mean and standard deviation?

Comment: Thats just a typo. corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be working quite okay, on Julia 1.8.5, OnlineStats v1.5.14 :

```
julia> using OnlineStats

julia> stats = Series(Mean(), Variance(), Extrema());

julia> fit!(stats, -1);

julia> fit!(stats, 1);

julia> values(stats)
Series
├─ Mean: n=2 | value=0.0
├─ Variance: n=2 | value=2.0
└─ Extrema: n=2 | value=(min = -1.0, max = 1.0, nmin = 1, nmax = 1)
```

```
julia> (ol_mean, ol_var, (ol_min, ol_max, ol_mincnt, ol_maxcnt)) = 
  value(stats)
(0.0, 2.0, (min = -1.0, max = 1.0, nmin = 1, nmax = 1))

julia> ol_std = sqrt(ol_var)
1.4142135623730951

julia> zdata = ([-1,1] .- ol_mean)/ol_std
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 -0.7071067811865475
  0.7071067811865475

julia> mean(zdata)
0.0

julia> std(zdata)
0.9999999999999999
```

Comment: Thank you Dan, but I don't understand why mean and std have to be taken on zdata?  Or really the purpose of zdata.

Comment: Just demonstration that `zdata` is scaled correctly by `ol_mean` and `ol_std`. So after normalizing `zdata` has 0.0 mean and 1.0 standard deviation. `[-1,1]` is the online data entered into `stats`

Comment: I see now, yes that looks fine then.  Thanks